# Зачем Stack Overflow завёл русскоязычную версию?

Tags: обсуждение

Если большинство программистов не поймут ответы на русском, зачем разбивать ответы на разноязычные страницы?

Comment: зачем задавать мета-вопросы на главной, если для этого есть мета?

Comment: Не спорю :)  мета коммент.

Comment: Если большинство не понимает китайского языка, то вообще зачем они(китайцы) существуют?))

Comment: Организация, стоящая за сайтом, коммерческая, следовательно основная причина - профит.

Comment: Вопрос следовало бы расширить еще как минимум на испанский, португальский и японский языки.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

На нашей планете насчитывается несколько тысяч языков. При этом подавляющее большинство людей знает только один родной язык. А языков программирования и вовсе не знают. Казалось бы, зачем вообще тогда нужны сайты группы Stack Overflow? А нужны они потому, что в абсолютном исчислении людей, интересующихся программированием, достаточно много. В это множество входят и люди, для которых английский язык не является в достаточной мере удобным для освоения какой-либо технологии. Кто-то понимает лишь отдельные слова, кто-то может читать, но имеет проблемы с письмом, а кто-то наоборот, живя и работая за рубежом, старается не забыть свой родной язык и потому публикует сообщения на локализованной версии Stack Overflow. Стоит заметить, что помимо русского существуют еще испанский, португальский и японский варианты Stack Overflow. Возможно, когда-нибудь появятся и другие. Главное условие для этого - наличие потенциальной аудитории, о которой я написал чуть выше, способной создать необходимый трафик и способствовать развитию сети сайтов Stack Exchange в целом. Хотя, вероятно есть и другие причины, так как иначе уже были бы *Stack Overflow 中國* и *Stack Overflow हिन्दी में*.

Comment: Спасибо за полный ответ. По голосам видно что многие соглассны. Хотя мое мнение остаётся критическим. Фактически происходит дробь ответов на вопросы которы могут не повторятся на других языках. Японцы не найдут ответов данные только на Русском языке.

Comment: @dbrin японцы также не найдут ответов и на enSO. Нужно учить эсперанто, хотя это тоже вряд ли поможет. :)

Comment: Правильно. Вот я о том же :)